# Rails Simple Form single checkbox twice in querystring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, simple-form

I have a search form which I return to after searching, to be able to refine the search. I just added a checkbox to that form.

In the view:

```
<%= f.input :available_tomorrow, as: :boolean, label: false,
  inline_label: t('public.search.form.available_tomorrow.label'),
  input_html: { name: :available_tomorrow, value: params[:available_tomorrow],
    id: :available_tomorrow } %>
```

In the model:

```
attr_reader :available_tomorrow
```

HTLM produced:

```
<div class="form-group boolean optional search_available_tomorrow">
  <input name="available_tomorrow" type="hidden" value="0">
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input class="boolean optional" id="available_tomorrow" name="available_tomorrow" type="checkbox" value="1">
    Available tomorrow
  </label>
</div>
```

When I check the box, all search parameters appear fine in the url querystring but that one:

```
&available_tomorrow=0&available_tomorrow=1
```

Looks like the value property of both field is sent, and neither changes. If I uncheck the box, I only get &available_tomorrow=0 in the querystring. The second part is only added if the checkbox is checked.

Everything works as intended (the search does return the right results depending on the checkbox state, the checkbox is in the right state when the search form is updated). But that querystring is ugly with both available_tomorrow parameters, looks like the first one should never appear. Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This is normal behavior for a form with a checkbox when you POST the form: If the checkbox is not checked, only the hidden field with value 0 is sent with the formdata. If the checkbox is checked, the input with the value 1 is also sent.

The hidden field for the checkbox is always sent, this is because otherwise no value for the checkbox would be sent.

Long story short: don't mind the querystring in your search url, nobody will ever look at them. :)